# When uploading image uri says null

Tags: android, firebase, file-upload, camera, firebase-storage

I am quiet new to firebase and i'm trying to upload a image on firebase and whenever I try to upload It always say that uri is null. So I made a if condition if its null then it wont do the uploading.

I am quiet sure that the image is taking picture because I made a imageview so I can see the picture I've taken and its working properly

This is the code I use for my camera

```
private void askCameraPermissions() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERM_CODE);
    }
    else
    {
        openCamera();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERM_CODE)
    {
        if (grantResults.length < 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            openCamera();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission Needed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void openCamera() {
    Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camera, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
        imageuri = data.getData();
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        selfie.setImageBitmap(image);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is the code I use to upload Image

```
private void uploadPicture() {

    if (imageuri != null) {
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setTitle("Uploading...");
        pd.show();

        StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        riversRef.putFile(imageuri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Attendance successful.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attendance Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                        double progressPercent = (100.00 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        pd.setMessage("Progress: " + (int) progressPercent + "%");
                    }
                });
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attendance Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course. You will only get a small bitmap for a thumbnail in onActivityResult. No uri as you know now.

Comment: `if (imageuri != null) ` You should check that before you call the upload function.

Comment: Is `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attendance Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` showing any message?